# How to Search and Extract Data From Website With a Shell Script?

Tags: shell, web

I would like to extract data from a website which has a search area.

The manual operation is to connect to the webpage via browser, enter a 5 digit number into a search text box and click search (although hitting enter works as well)

The page which is returned displays the information required.

I have been looking at the source information of the page and I can't see anything that would allow me to simply enter a single URL with =12345

Is it possible to write a shell script which performs the search from the main page and extracts the simple data there after?

There is nothing complicated about the page, it doesn't require a user name and password and all the information is public.

Comment: You can use **curl** to get the data from the page.

Comment: Yes it is - You can use your browser and have a look, how the request looks like. In Firefox Press CTRL+Shift+I and go to 'Network'. Then insert your Number and press 'Return'. Now you should see what kind of request was sended (GET, POST or PUT) and the parameters.

Comment: your options include `curl`, `lynx` and `wget`.

Comment: Thanks for the firefox tip. it looks like the site is using ajax to pre search the the search field. I can't see that I am sending any information or url after return is entered

Comment: It looks like I get a request only though XHR